# How to list existing alias for a certain linux user?

Tags: login, alias

Does anyone know how do I list existing alias for a certain Unix/Linux user on Debian?
For example I have an Unix/Linux user 1001 and want to know which alias for login it has?

Comment: What do you mean by alias? Do you mean the user name?

Answer (score 7):

I assume you have a user with a numerical user id (`uid`) of 1001 and want its user name:

```
getent passwd 1001
```

will show this information.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a local user you can grep `/etc/passwd` for it. Like following:

```
grep 1001 /etc/passwd
```

If it's a non-local user, it depends on the DB backend that is used to store him in. For example if you use NIS you may check with `ypcat`:

```
cd /etc
ypcat passwd | grep 1001
```

For other DB backends you'll have to check the specific ways to search for a user by UID.

Comment: See my approach. This will work with `LDAP`, `NIS` etc.

Comment: This isn't good. What if there is a UID 1001 and a UID 11001?